# Can real-space-eigenstates of conduction electrons in crystal cause formation of electronic singlet pairs?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

Crystals may contain electronic real-space-eigenstates as ground states, which are spatially much larger than one unit cell, such as impurity states, standing waves at Brillouin zone edges, Anderson localization, etc. Every eigenstate is usually occupied by two conduction electrons with opposite spins, forming a singlet pair. Notably: if the eigenstate is limited in real space, then the excitation energy of each singlet electron is not necessarily negligible, so below a certain temperature the singlet pair can be lasting. Isn't this a long-debated pairing mechanism in superconductors ?

Comment: I am not really following your argument here. Could you expend your reasoning a little? I am also not quite sure what your actual is

Comment: Crystal may have eigenstates, trapping conduction electrons due to multiple scattering on lattice sites. These local states are not necessarily atomic orbitals. Inside some local states electron can tunnel for distance much longer than atomic orbital. However, the free path is limited in space, so the electron remains trapped for a while in the limited area. The trapping area (like usual potential well) can contain only two identical electrons with opposite spins. Thus, there is a singlet pair in the large local area. The question: is this pair formation related to pairing in superconductors?